# JMeter Login once and do an operation multiple times

Tags: session, cookies, jmeter, session-cookies, jmeter-plugins

I have a test plan such as:

```
-Test Plan
  - Thread Group
      - Cookie Manager
      - Login
      - Play
```

The login operation returns a session cookie which is required for play operation, for which I'm using Cookie Manager.

Now, the login operation should happen only once and play operation should happen 1000 times. How can I do it? I know that each thread in the thread group represents individual user. So how should I arrange this test?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and structure your test this way:

[image: Test plan configuration]

Comment: Please can you tell what is the difference between the Cookie Manager being directly under Test Plan and directly under Thread Group?

Comment: Just the scope, if under thread group it only applies to it, if under test plan it applies to all thread groups. If answer is ok, yoy should accept it. Thanks

Comment: You can also do it using a Only Once Controller for login request, and play request outside the controller.